# Enable JMX for CamelTestSupport

Tags: apache-camel

Can we register Managed Routes,Managed Processors and other ManagedBeans of the camelcontext from the CamlTestSupport class.So that we can see the JMX statistics of the routes and processors of camelTestSupport's camel context.If we can register,how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes override the `useJmx` method and return true.

- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-test/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/junit4/CamelTestSupport.java#L440

Then when jmx is enabled then Camel will enlist all those mbeans during testing.

There is a few unit tests we enable jmx when testing with blueprint here, you can take a look at

- https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-test-blueprint/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/test/blueprint/management

Comment: Links doesn't work